# Hide dependent variable in output

Tags: output-formatting

I recently started to work with Mathematica in the field of Robotics.
In that type of research there are lot of matrices like this random example
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos{(q_1(t)+q_2(t))}&\sin{(q_1(t)+q_2(t))}\\ \sin{(q_1(t))}&\cos{(q_2(t))}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, for better visibility I want Mathematica to

- hide the time-dependency, i.e. $q_1(t)$ should be displayed as $q_1$. Of course I still want to able to derive the derivative, which should be displayed as $q_1'$.
- I want to abbreviate the $sin$ and $cos$-terms like in the text-books:
  $\cos{(x)} = c_x$, $\sin{(x)} = s_x$,$\cos{(x+y)} = c_{xy}$, $\sin{(x+y)} = s_{xy}$

Anybody knows how to do that?
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own `...Form` wrapper that will perform requested formatting:

```
myForm // ClearAll
myForm /: MakeBoxes[myForm@expr_, form_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MakeBoxes},
    Function[{sym, long, short},
      MakeBoxes[sym@x_, form] := TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[x, form]}, "myForm",
        DisplayFunction -> (TooltipBox[SubscriptBox[short, #], RowBox@{long, "[", #, "]"}]&),
        InterpretationFunction -> (RowBox@{long, "[", #, "]"}&)
      ];
      MakeBoxes[sym@Plus@x__, form] := TemplateBox[
        Replace[Unevaluated@{x}, a_ :> MakeBoxes[a, form], {1}],
        "myForm",
        DisplayFunction -> (TooltipBox[SubscriptBox[short, RowBox@{##}], RowBox@{long, "[", RowBox@{#1, "+", "..."}, "]"}]&),
        InterpretationFunction -> (RowBox@{long, "[", RowBox@Riffle[{##}, "+"], "]"}&)
      ]
    ] @@@ {{Sin, "Sin", "s"}, {Cos, "Cos", "c"}};
    MakeBoxes[h_@t, form] := TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[h, form]}, "myForm",
      DisplayFunction -> (TooltipBox[#, RowBox@{#, "[", "t", "]"}]&),
      InterpretationFunction -> (RowBox@{#, "[", "t", "]"}&)
    ];
    TagBox[MakeBoxes[expr, form], myForm]
  ]
myForm // If[Not@MemberQ[$OutputForms, #],
  With[{protected = Unprotect@$OutputForms},
    PrependTo[$OutputForms, #];
    Protect@protected;
  ]
]&
```

You can use it as any other `...Form` wrapper:

```
{{Cos[Subscript[q, 1][t] + Subscript[q, 2][t]], Sin[Subscript[q, 1][t] + Subscript[q, 2][t]]},
 {Sin[Subscript[q, 1][t]], Cos[Subscript[q, 1][t]] }}
% // myForm
% // MatrixForm
% // MatrixForm // myForm
```

[image: myForm results]

If you want to format every output without manually adding `myForm` to each line, you can assign it to [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html):

```
$PrePrint = myForm
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly!