# Factoring an arbitrary power from the rest of the expression in an exponential expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have the following expression:

```
Exp[r*t*x + e*r*y + t*x*r^2 + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]]
```

I want to choose some arbitrary terms in the power and for example write the expression in the form:

```
Exp[t*x*r^2] Exp[r*t*x + e*r*y + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]]]
```

or as another example for choosing `t*x*r^2` and `r*t*x`

```
Exp[t*x*r^2] Exp[r*t*x] Exp[e*r*y + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]]]
```

How can I do this manipulation of expressions?

Answer (score 1):

From your earlier question you know Mathematica likes to combine exponentials automatically. If this is for display purposes only the you can do

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
expr = Exp[r*t*x + e*r*y + t*x*r^2 + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]]
```

$$
e^{e \sqrt{r} y^2+e r y+r^2 t x+r t x}
$$

```
term = t*x*r^2
Dot[Exp[(Last@expr /. term -> 0)], Exp[term]]
```

$$
e^{e \sqrt{r} y^2+e r y+r t x}.e^{r^2 t x}
$$

And for your second example

```
term = r*t*x
Dot[Exp[(Last@expr /. term -> 0)], Exp[term]]
```

$$
e^{e \sqrt{r} y^2+e r y+r^2 t x}.e^{r t x}
$$

But the result is `Dot` and you'd have to replace that with `*` to use it.  The above method ofcourse works on the example you have shown. It is not meant to be a general method as it does no checking, (for example, it assumes the argument inside `Exp` is a sum of terms.

but with more error checking it can be made into a Module and used as black box.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function:

```
factorizeExp[expr_, lst_] := Module[{exprA, exprB},
  exprA = expr[[2]][[Sequence@lst]];
  exprB = expr[[2]] - exprA;
  Inactive[Exp][exprA]*Inactive[Exp][exprB]
  ]
```

where the arguments are as follows: *expr* is the expression to be factorized, and *lst* is the list of terms in the exponent that you need to present as a separate exponent. For example, if you wish to separate out the terms `r*t*x + t*x*r^2` you make `lst={1,3}`.

Let us try this function

```
factorizeExp[Exp[r*t*x + e*r*y + t*x*r^2 + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]], {4}]

(*  Inactive[Exp][e Sqrt[r] y^2] Inactive[Exp][r t x + r^2 t x + e r y]*)

factorizeExp[Exp[r*t*x + e*r*y + t*x*r^2 + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]], {1}]

(*    Inactive[Exp][r t x] Inactive[Exp][r^2 t x + e r y + e Sqrt[r] y^2] *)
    
factorizeExp[Exp[r*t*x + e*r*y + t*x*r^2 + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]], {1, 4}]

  (*  Inactive[Exp][r^2 t x + e r y] Inactive[Exp][r t x + e Sqrt[r] y^2]  *)
```

On the screen, you will see a bit different image than you see above. Here is what you see on the screen:

[image]

The expression is inactivated. If you intend to make further calculations with it, do not forget to first activate it with the function `Activate`. Its application, however, removes the formatting.

Instead of `Inactivate` one can use `HoldForm` as follows:

```
factorizeExp2[expr_, lst_] := Module[{exprA, exprB},
  exprA = expr[[2]][[Sequence@lst]];
  exprB = expr[[2]] - exprA;
  HoldForm[Evaluate[Exp[exprA]]]*HoldForm[Evaluate[Exp[exprB]]]
  ]
```

Then its application

```
expr = factorizeExp2[
  Exp[r*t*x + e*r*y + t*x*r^2 + y^2*e*Sqrt[r]], {1, 4}]
```

returns the following:

[image]

For further calculation (if any) you need to apply `ReleaseHold` to it. Some more details please find in my recent post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259109/rearrange-the-parts-of-formula-expression/259113#259113)

Have fun!